# White screen appear while opening an android app.. Not showing anything

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, wifi

I was create a android application using apache cordova with angularjs. When i build a apk and deploy to my mobile, its working fine. But when we deployed to client side, its showing only white screen.

And when switch off my wifi on client mobile then application was opened. but its not use for me because all database connectivity performs using wifi. When i switch on wifi then the screen will goes to white screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling some data from server when mobile app starts. Based on data returned by server you are showing page in mobile application. But at client side that ajax call is getting failed. So write appropriate handling code for ajax failure function also.

Comment: Thanks @Nitish, You are correct am calling some data from a server when mobile app starts. But When i installed app on client tablet in my my office environment. and go to the client side its working fine. But I un install on same tab and again install the same app and same tablet in client environment means its not working, the white screen was appear. This is my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From office & client environment do you mean development and production server?

Comment: There are only two possible reasons now  
1. You have not added <access> for your production server in config.xml for mobile application. please refer whitelist plugin also.  
2. There is some security certificate issue (if you are using) with production server.